# gcloud console how to get user's account status?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a lot of projects that have been abandoned. Thousands in fact. Rather than go through each project one at a time and delete them, I want to get a list of projects by the owners account status which should be active or inactive.

What I have so far is:

```
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} --flatten=bindings --filter=bindings.role:roles/owner --format='value(bindings.members)'
done
```

What command can take the value returned by get-iam-policy and determine whether or not the users account is Active or Inactive?

Comment: What are you trying to determine is inactive - the project or the user account?

Comment: The user who owns the project.